# UIKit - Place own statusbar above UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, statusbar

My app is in landscape and uses a **UINavigationController** as its RootViewController. My goal with it is:

- Disable the normal iOS StatusBar ( I know how to do that and already did it )
- Have a semi-transparent StatusBar (a view) above the **UINavigationBar**, so that I can show custom information on it
- Parts of the content of my main view must be visible underneath my custom StatusBar (exactly like it works with the normal **UIStatusBar**, just that I don't want the clock and battery and want to show my own information on it)

How can I best achieve this?

Comment: You could use this library https://github.com/frankdilo/FDStatusBarNotifierView. Also, check the advanced settings for manual hide (in your case you won't hide it). And add your content as a subview to this.

Comment: You mean add my UINavigationController with the content as a subview to that status bar? I want my main view to cover the whole screen (also under the status bar), do think this will work this way?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on [**GitHub**](https://github.com) gave me multiple libraries that offer the exact functionality you are looking for.

- [MTStatusBarOverlay](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay)
- [KGStatusBar](https://github.com/kevingibbon/KGStatusBar)
- [CWStatusBarNotification](https://github.com/cezarywojcik/CWStatusBarNotification)
- [FDStatusBarNotifierView](https://github.com/frankdilo/FDStatusBarNotifierView)
- [BWStatusBarOverlay](https://github.com/brunow/BWStatusBarOverlay)
- [WTStatusBar](https://github.com/pieceofsummer/WTStatusBar)
- [TWStatus](https://github.com/petersantino/TWStatus)

**Try them out, test them and see which one is best for you.**

*If none of them are good enough, you should get an idea on how to achieve this functionality using the source code those libraries provide.*

Comment: I know these and am using the BWStatusBarOverlay at the moment. The problem with all these is that it is not possible to show them above the UINavigationBar and at the same time show the view of the UINavigationController underneath the new status bar.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 Human Interface Design, page 143 says:

> Don’t create a custom status bar. Users depend on the consistency of
>   the system-provided status bar. Although you might hide the status bar
>   in your app, it’s not appropriate to create custom UI that takes its
>   place.

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html)